# Como acessar uma página através de urls amigáveis dinamicamente?

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Bom, eu devo estar querendo uma coisa muito complicada para um iniciante mas vamos lá ...

Estou iniciando um sistema aonde preciso criar urls dinâmicas e amigáveis para cadastrar todas as informações referentes a uma página no banco de dados e chamar estas informações quando a página for acessada. O problema é que eu não conheço muito bem ainda **.htaccess**. Peço ajuda!!!

> **htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pagina=$1
</IfModule>
```

**Pergunta:** Como e que tipo de relação existe entre a página e o conteúdo no banco de dados para que quando chamar a url, venha o conteúdo. Alguma coisa tipo, se for **/index.php?pagina=contato** chama o conteúdo **x**  <**http://darte.axitech.com.br/index.php?pagina=contato**>

Consigo **não** receber um erro digitando <**http://darte.axitech.com.br/contato**> ... será que ele já está realmente redirecionando, roteando para /contato?

Comment: Parece tudo certo, qual é o problema?

Comment: @bfavaretto o que eu pergunto é: como e que tipo de relação devo aplicar a página e ao conteúdo no banco de dados para que quando chamar a url, venha o conteúdo. Alguma coisa tipo, se for **/index.php?pagina=contato** chama o conteúdo **x** ...

Comment: No index php você vê o que tem em `$_GET['pagina']`. Vai ser o nome da página. Com base nisso você puxa e mostra o conteúdo adequado.

Comment: Uma maneira de fazer isso de forma mais prática seria atribuir um ID para cada página e depois chamar o conteúdo pelo ID da própria?

Comment: Depende do que você quer fazer. `/contato` faz mais sentido que `/72`. Em outros casos, de coleções com muitos itens, faz mais sentido usar o ID (às vezes seguido de um *slug* do título).

Comment: Eu recomendaria fazer uma busca por microframeworks de php, e usar um que resolva o roteamento pra você.

Comment: Mas tipo ... isso não influencia no SEO passar algum parametro na "url amigável"? Ou é uma pratica não tão ruim assim? Tem outra forma de buscar o conteúdo sem enviar o paramento na url?

Comment: Você precisa deixar claro pro PHP qual é o conteúdo que ele tem de entregar. E para fins de SOE precisa fazer isso da forma mais elegante possível. Mas o que você passa depende de como está estruturada a sua aplicação/site.

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi o teu problema, mas me parece que talvez você queira que `pagina=` seja um script php, no caso o teu index.php esta chamando por variavel, mas isto não é obrigatorio, vai depender de como usar o regex no caso poderia fazer assim `RewriteRule "^(.*)(|/)$" "$1.php [QSA,L]"` - O QSA passa os parametros GET pra nova página, se acessar assim: `http://localhost/contato?foo=1` vai apontar pra algo como `/contato.php?foo=1`, se fizer assim `http://localhost/a/b/c/d?foo=1` vai apontar pra algo como `/a/b/c/d.php?foo=1`

Comment: Sobre o uso do `[L]` eu expliquei aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95399/3635

Comment: Uma duvida @MarcosVinicius isto você esta usando com CodeIgniter?