# Mesclar 2 condições do mod_rewrite no .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Sobre .htaccess e mod_rewrite não entendendo absolutamente nada!

A situação é a seguinte, possuo 2 projetos em domínios distintos:

1. Este primeiro projeto utiliza a condição abaixo que direciona o navegador sempre para o protocolo HTTPS desabilitando a navegação por HTTP.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
   ```
2. Este segundo projeto utiliza a condição abaixo que habilita a navegação por URL's amigáveis.

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
   ```

A questão agora é, preciso mesclar estas condições para um 3º projeto, pois o mesmo possui SSL (HTTPS) habilitado e também a reescrita para URL amigáveis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que sim, basta usar um `RewriteCond` antes de seu `RewriteRule` especifico e também talvez seja necessário usar a [flag `[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Se tiver algum erro, me comunique.

Comment: Pô Guilherme, pela lógica fiz exatamente isso que fez só que sem a flag, retornou "Redirecionamento incorreto" no navegador, foi só colocar a tal da flag que não tinha nenhum conhecimento que funcionou. Agora darei uma lida no link que postou sobre as flags rs, valeu!